# Am I using ForEach correctly?

Tags: firebase

I'm working on a presence-like system in firebase with following layout:

```
firebase {
   user1 {
     isOnline: true
   }
   user 2 {
     isOnline: true
   }
   user3 {
     isOnline: false
   }
}
```

The isOnline booleans are what I am going to use later to output the names of the users that are online to the console

So for example, in the case above it would say:

```
user1 is online.
user2 is online.
```

Here is my code:

```
var gameRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");
var userOnline = new Firebase('https://xxx/.info/connected');

        userOnline.on('value', function (snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.val()) {
               gameRef.child(user).update({
                    isOnline : true
                });
          }
          else {
              gameRef.child(user).update({
                    isOnline : false
                });
          }
        });

       // for each user that is online, output to the console
       gameRef.forEach(function (snapshot) {
            var obj = snapshot.val();
            if(obj.isOnline == true) {
                console.log(obj.name + " is online.");
            }
        });
```

There seems to be a problem with my forEach, how can I fix this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot `forEach` over a ref, but only over a snapshot.

```
   // for each user that is online, output to the console
   gameRef.on('value', function(function(gamesSnapshot) {
       gamesSnapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {
           var obj = snapshot.val();
           if(obj.isOnline == true) {
               console.log(obj.name + " is online.");
           }
       }
   });
```

This code has two snapshot variables:

- `gameSnapshot` is the data in the parent node
- `snapshot` is the data of a specific player

### Alternative

The approach above will download all players, even though you are only looking to deal with players that are online. It is more efficient in this case, to query Firebase so that it only returns players that are online.

```
   // for each user that is online, output to the console
   var onlinePlayers = gameRef.orderByChild('isOnline').equalTo(true);
   onlinePlayers.on('child_added', function(function(snapshot) {
       var obj = snapshot.val();
       if(obj.isOnline == true) {
           console.log(obj.name + " is online.");
       }
   });
```

The code now listens for the `child_added` event, since Firebase spoon-feeds us the players one at a time. You will probably also have to handle `child_changed` and `child_removed`, once you map the players to HTML elements.

Even though this will result in a bit more code, I would normally recommend using querying and the `child_*` events, since they limit the data that Firebase sends you both initially and when e.g. a player goes offline.

Comment: Hey Frank, I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error, any ideas? Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/b03nh7oj/

Comment: You're using Firebase client 1.1.1. `orderByChild` was added in 2.0. Note that "undefined is not a function" is an extremely common error to get in JavaScript and you'd do well to learn how to debug it. I simply added a `debugger` statement to your code and stepped through it in Fiddler to find what line broke. Then it's quite easy to figure out what part of the line is wrong in the console tab of the browser's dev tools.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Words of Gold,"You cannot forEach over a ref, but only over a snapshot.". Something i wish Google had put up on their site, wouldnt have lost so much time!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen AFAIK, `forEach` is an array method but `snapshot` are objects so I'm at wits end as to how `forEach` works on `snapshot` objects. Is that a polyfill, ES6 feature or a `snapshots` own internal method. Can u please shed more light on this. Thanks.