# Calling a Firebase Cloud Function 'ForEach' child of a Snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, twilio, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Firebase Cloud Function that sends a text message to its associated recipient for x number of text messages. The function is triggered in my iOS app when an update is made to the 'send' Realtime Database reference, indicating that the user has pressed the 'send' button.

My Firebase structure is

```
  {
  "user1uid": {
    "send": false
    "messagesToSend": {
      "messageuid1": {
         "messageText": "What's for dinner?",
         "recipientNumber": "+18017378888",
      }
      "messageuid2:
         "messageText": "Who won the Cowboys game?",
         "recipientNumber": "+18017377787",
      }
   }
   "user2uid": {
    "send": false
    "messagesToSend": {
      "messageuid1": {
         "messageText": "What's for dinner?",
         "recipientNumber": "+18017378888",
      }
      "messageuid2:
         "messageText": "Who won the Cowboys game?",
         "recipientNumber": "+18017377787",
      }
   }
}
```

My code currently only sends one message, and I'm not sure how I can properly iterate through the **messagesToSend** node for each user and send all the messages in it.

I've been trying to follow the tutorial [located here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sms-texting-with-twilio/). I have looked at the following Stack Overflow responses but am unable to decipher or derive a solution from them:

[Firebase cloud function promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827392/firebase-cloud-function-promises)
[Am I using ForEach correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181691/am-i-using-foreach-correctly)

My index.js code that sends one message is as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const twilio = require('twilio')

const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid;
const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token;

const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const twilioNumber = functions.config().twilio.number;


// Start cloud function
exports.sendSecrets = functions.database
       .ref('/{uid}/send')
       .onUpdate((change,context) => {

    const uid = context.params.uid;

    return admin.database().ref(uid+'/messagesToSend').once('value').then(snapshot => {

      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          var messageData = childSnapshot.val();
          **if (messageData.sanitized) return true;**
          var message = messageData.messageText;
          var phoneNumber = messageData.recipientNumber;

          const textMessage = {
            body: `From My App - ${message}`,
            from: twilioNumber, // From Twilio number
            to: phoneNumber  // Text to this number
          }
          return client.messages.create(textMessage)
        })
        **return snapshot.ref.toString();**
    });
});
```

Please note that the lines marked with ** at either end indicate that I know I need to return something based on error messages I received indicating that 'Each then() should return a value or throw'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make the assumption that you are using the `twilio-node` library that use promises: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio.

Since you want to send several messages in parallel, you have to use `Promise.all()`, as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const twilio = require('twilio')

const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid;
const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token;

const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const twilioNumber = functions.config().twilio.number;


// Start cloud function
exports.sendSecrets = functions.database
       .ref('/{uid}/send')
       .onUpdate((change,context) => {

    const uid = context.params.uid;

    return admin.database().ref(uid+'/messagesToSend').once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {

      const promises = [];

      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          var messageData = childSnapshot.val();
          //**if (messageData.sanitized) return true;**
          var message = messageData.messageText;
          var phoneNumber = messageData.recipientNumber;

          const textMessage = {
            body: `From My App - ${message}`,
            from: twilioNumber, // From Twilio number
            to: phoneNumber  // Text to this number
          }

          promises.push(client.messages.create(textMessage));
      })

      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    // Edits made below to parentheses/brackets
    .then(results => {
      //Do whatever you want !!
      // e.g. print the results which will be an array of messages
      // (see https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node#testing-your-installation)
    })            
});
```

You can also simply return `Promise.all()` as follows:

```
....
     return Promise.all(promises);
   })
});
```

Comment: Thank you Renaud, I just edited a few brackets/parentheses you no doubt typed quickly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: considered and done, thank you again. Do you perhaps know what call I would make to print out all the message data thats been sent? (e.g. to, from and messageText/body?) I know it's console.log but I've tried `.then((message) => console.log(message));` and it only returns the number of the recipient..

Comment: @northsydneybears Sorry I don't really know the Twilio SDKs and API. But according to the doc (https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node#testing-your-installation), the `create()` method returns a Promise that resolves with a `message` object. And the API documentation for this kind of object is here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message. There are some `from` and `to` properties, among others. The messages returned by `Promise.all()` will be contained in the `results` array. This array is ordered in the same order than the `promises` array. Hope this helps!